# Why this code doesnt allocate memory in C++?

Tags: c++

this is the Book class

```
//book.h
#include<iostream>
class Book
{
public:
int _isbn;
};
```

this is the BookList class

```
//book_list.h
#include"book.h" 
class BookList
{
pubblic:
BookList(int limit);
Book** _list;
};
```

book_list.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"book.h"
#include"book_list.h"
BookList::BookList(int limit)
{
 _list = new Book*[limit]
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"book.h"
#include"book_list.h"
int main()
{
  BookList myList(5);
  myList._list[1]->_isbn = 4; // here I get the crash
}
```

why I cant change something in `_list[i]`?

Comment: You allocate memory for some pointers, but what do those pointers point to? This is undefined behavior.

Comment: You are allocating pointers to Books, but no actual Books. How about `std::vector<Book>`?

Comment: Because `_list` has been initialized with the pointer returned by `new`, but `_list[1]` is still uninitialized. Please, don't use custom list since you're a C++ beginner. Use `std::vector<Book>` instead.

Comment: You can always do: `Book* list = new Book[limit];  list[0].isbn = 4;  list[1].isbn = 10;`  In other words.. do you really need an array of `Book` pointers? OR is an array of `Book` what you want?

Comment: i wanted array of Book pointers , I just forgot to allocate memory for each pointer , thank you

Answer (score 5):

You allocate memory for pointers to `Book`. You need to allocate memory for `Book`s to which the pointers to point to.

```
_list = new Book*[limit]
for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
   _list[i] = new Book;
}
```

This fixes the error in your code, but are you sure you want this? If you need a simple dynamic array of `Book`s, `std::vector<Book>` is the way to go.

Obviously, as a rule, every `new` must be accompanied by a `delete` and every `new[]` must be accompanied by a `delete[]` - in order to not have a memory leak.

```
// this goes into the destructor
for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
   delete _list[i]; 
}
delete[] _list;
```

Comment: You should also add the deleter code, I think.. I'm not 100% sure if OP will understand how to delete it..  `for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) { delete list[i]; list[i] = NULL; }; delete[] list; list = NULL;`